# How to copy keys from hash to array without duplicates?

Tags: perl

If I have an array and hash like these

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @a = qw/a b c d e/;
my %h = (a => 1, b => 1, f => 1, g => 1);
```

and I would like to end up with `@a` containing all of the keys from `%h`, and no element in the array must appear more than once.

How can that be done, as `exists` doesn't work on arrays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make use of [`List::MoreUtils`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aMoreUtils)'s `uniq` function:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( uniq );

@a = uniq @a, keys %h;
```

Comment: This is a union of @a and keys %h; she may have wanted an intersection?

Comment: I do not think that she intended an intersection. Relevant section: `@a` _containing all of the keys from_ `%h`.

Answer (score 6):

If you have Perl 5.10 and later, you can use smart matching (`~~`):

```
for my $key (keys %h) {        
    push @a, $key unless $key ~~ @a;      
}
```

Otherwise, `List::Util`'s `first` can help:

```
for my $key (keys %h) {        
    push @a, $key unless first { $_ eq $key } @a;      
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Convert the values you want into hash keys, then extract them

```
my %foo = map { $_ => 1  } @a, keys %h;
print sort keys %foo;
```

Comment: Or just `@a = keys %{{ map {$_ => 1} @a, keys %h }}`

Answer (score 4):

How about this (admittedly destructive to `%h):

```
delete @h{ @a }; # delete all keys of h already in @a
push @a, keys %h; # push remaining keys onto @a
```

Thus @a retains the order it had and simply appends the non-duplicate keys in `%h`.

A word about the destructiveness: The example above illustrates some concepts of what can be done when you can afford to be destructive. And delete is certainly no more destructive than passing out of the scope of a lexical variable.

The issue can be addressed by simply copying it to another hash before narrowing the hash to those keys not found in `@a`.

```
my %h2 = %h;
delete @h2{ @a };
push @a, keys %h2;
```